# Partial change array ElasticSearch

Tags: java, arrays, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I use ElasticSearch 2.3.3.
Now i need update the one of many arrays in documents in my index.
This a part of document in ElasticSearch:

```
      "sizes": [
         {
            "characteristicId": 11154209,
            "localized": [
               {
                  "country": "kz",
                  "price": 19580,
                  "priceWithSale": 15460,
                  "quantity": 6
               },
               {
                  "country": "ru",
                  "price": 3660,
                  "priceWithSale": 2891,
                  "quantity": 6
               }
            ],
            "typeId": 0,
            "sizeName": "35",
            "wbSize": {
               "id": 19,
               "value": "35"
            },
            "techSize": {
               "id": 58,
               "value": "35"
            }
         }
      ]
```

I try to use feature ["Update by merging documents"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.3/java-docs-update.html#java-docs-update-api-merge-docs) on Java-API like this:

```
updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
            updateRequest.index("index)";
            updateRequest.type("type");
            updateRequest.id("2148069");

                    updateRequest.doc(XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject()
                            .startArray("sizes")
                                .startObject()
                                    .field("characteristicId", 9099140)
                                    .startArray("localized")
                                        .startObject()
                                            .field("country", "kz")
                                            .field("price", 15)
                                            .field("priceWithSale", 15)
                                        .endObject()
                                        .startObject()
                                            .field("country", "ru")
                                            .field("price", 3)
                                            .field("priceWithSale", 3)
                                        .endObject()
                                    .endArray()
                                .endObject()
                            .endArray()
                        .endObject());

            client.update(updateRequest).get();
```

But it is just rewriting the entire array, while i need update some fields in array.
Is there some way?